# Inverse limits of quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, limits-colimits

Let $A\subset B$ be an extension of discrete valuation rings and let $p$ and $P$ be the non-zero prime ideals of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

So I can write $pB=P^m$ for some $m>0$.

I form the inverse limit $\varprojlim B/p^nB$ with respect to the inverse system $\{B/p^nB,\pi_m^n\}$ where $\pi_m^n$ is the residue class map $B/p^nB\to B/p^mB$ for $n\geq m$.

> Then is it true that $\varprojlim B/p^nB=\varprojlim B/P^n$?

Comment: Do you mean for your rings to be discrete valuation rings? Otherwise there's no reason $pB$ should be a power of the (what i assume you intend as) the maximal ideal of $B$.

Comment: Yes what I want is $pB$ to be a power of $P$ so I think you are right.